# Ignore Dev Files When Using Pull

Tags: git, github

I have been using git for a week or so and am now using two branches. I have the master branch and a dev branch. My dev branch contains files that I do not want in the main branch such as node_modules, .sass-cache, etc... So I make my edits in the dev branch, but when I try to pull the changes into my master branch all the files/folder come with it. Is there a way to pull in only the files that are relevant to the master branch?

Answer (score 2):

Use git merge with --no-commit. You will have to do it locally.

```
git merge --no-commit branch-to-merge
```

This will allow you to revert or get rid of files you don't want in master before committing.

Comment: `merge` doesn't copy the files; it simply makes the commits available from `master`. (Although, I guess this is just a question of keeping the files out of your checkout, or keeping them completely out of the history of `master`.)

Comment: @chepner Definitely. I got the impression that OP wanted to keep the folders/files in question out of master, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You may already committed these files in `dev` branch.

The right way is not put these files under SCM.

Add the rule of these file to `.gitignore`.

and if you already committed them, then remove them like:

```
git rm --cached .sass-cache
```

Comment: There may be very good reasons to keep the files in source control without having them in every branch.

Comment: They may be files you use during the development process, but aren't needed for deployment. `vim`, for example, can use a directory-local config file which you might want to keep under source control during development, but doesn't need to be in the `master` branch.

Comment: @chepner These files should just stay in the working directory, I don't see any merit to put the files (such as cache) under source control. Put in source control just for tracking the change?

Comment: Why not? Also, you're assuming only one person uses the dev branch, or only one machine. Keeping it on source control ensures it is available anywhere you clone the repository.  (Cache, yes, should be kept out, as it can be regenerated as necessary. But I was under the impression that there were non-cache files involved as well.)

Comment: @chepner I didn't assume that at all. I mean, such cache files should not be kept in source control, it you change your machine or someone else cloned the repo, such files should be produced by program but not fetch from repo.

Comment: @chepner And even if you put them under source control, how do you prevent merge them into other branch?

Comment: That's his exact question.

Comment: @chepner So, what would you do in such situation, could you post your answer ?

Comment: I never claimed to have an answer; I like Phil's approach of manually intervening before committing the merge, but it's unclear to me if the files are to be kept out of any checkout of master, or kept out of master's history altogether. Otherwise, all I can think of is to not merge, but to cherry-pick commits that do not reference the dev-only files.  (And I think everyone would agree that approach is too painful to seriously consider.)